# Catkin build corruption after interruption

Tags: python, ros, catkin

I interrupted (Ctrl+C) a `catkin build` execution when it hadn't started to actually build files. Now, I can't run it again because some file seems to be corrupted. I get this error when I execute `catkin build` on the workspace:

```
$ catkin build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkin", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('catkin-tools', 'console_scripts', 'catkin')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/commands/catkin.py", line 258, in main
    catkin_main(sysargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/commands/catkin.py", line 253, in catkin_main
    sys.exit(args.main(args) or 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/verbs/catkin_build/cli.py", line 418, in main
    summarize_build=opts.summarize  # Can be True, False, or None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/verbs/catkin_build/build.py", line 245, in build_isolated_workspace
    for (k, v) in existing_buildspace_marker_data.items():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by removing the file `<workspace>/build/.catkin_tools.yaml`.